# Searching for a string in an ArrayList object

Tags: java, string, search

I have an `ArrayList` of type **Player** and I am trying to *search for a specific string* and I'm having a lot of trouble.

Currently I'm using a *boolean* to see **if the player contains the string**. Then I use a for *loop* to search the list.

But it keeps outputting the final line of the file; I'm pretty sure im not searching properly.

```
String playerName = sc.next();
    boolean isFound = players.contains(playerName);
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        if (isFound) {
            break;
        }
        index = i;

    }
    System.out.println(players.get(index));
    System.out.println(isFound);
```

My Player class is defined as follows
(not sure if this helps)

```
public class Player extends Person {
    public String pos;
    public int g;
    public int ab;
    public int r;  // various statistics for the player

    public Player(String name, String team, String pos) {
        this.name = name;
        this.team = team;
        this.pos = pos;
    }
```

And i also have a league class containing the lists

```
public class League extends loadData {
public static ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
public static ArrayList<Pitcher> pitchers = new ArrayList<Pitcher>();
```

}

If anyone can help me out that would be much appreciated!

Comment: `int index = players.indexOf(playerName); boolean isFound = index >= 0;`.

Comment: do `boolean isFound = players.contains(playerName);` inside the loop while iterating.

Comment: What is the property of "type Player" that you need to compare against?

Comment: Can you provide the Test-Case (should have found): playerName and your observerved match contained, please! Maybe it's an issue with character encoding.

Comment: Can you please update your post for declaration of _class_ **Player** so we now the type of list elements. This affects search and results!

Answer (score 0):

#### what's happening with your code

`isFound` is set **only before loop**. That's totally ok for checking if the [string is contained within the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943582/use-of-contains-in-java-arrayliststring).

If the list doesn't contain the string, then the loop will never break and iterating through all elements. So in this case your index-counter `i` will **point to the last element** which then gets printed after the loop.

#### clarify type of list elements VS type of searched

If your list stores objects of `Player` you couldn't simply compare them to searched object `String`. Maybe you can — on each element of the list — compare for `player.toString().contains(playerName)` or you can check for `player.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(playerName)`.

The type of you list's elements and it's declaration matter and need to be known (to us) in order to solve this.

#### solving search and print finding

> assuming the list contains elements of type string, i.e. `ArrayList<String> players`

To check if an element (here string `playerName`) is contained you can use either (Array)List's `indexOf` or `contains` method.
**Note:** the string could be 0, 1, or multiple times contained in the list. The approaches above only find first or no occurrence.

For printing you can either print the search-term `playerName` directly if found. Or you can use the returned first found index of method-call `index` to get the matching element and print that.
**Note:** The text printed should be the same in both options, although instance-ids/hashCodes could vary.

Comment: Even then, only if its a list of strings, and if the goal to to determine if one of the strings is exactly equal to the player name, not if it is a substring thereof.

Comment: Hmm all of that makes sense but The string IS contained in the array so I assume the loop should break. I also tried it with the full string and it still outputted the last line. So im sure the problem lies within my loop

Comment: In the question it was mentioned "arrayList of type Players", syntactically that would mean ArrayList<Player> ie not List<String>

Comment: @wissamhammoud if you search for partial strings contained, this needs loop and `element.contains(partialPlayerName)`

Comment: @Jayr Totally aware of that detail. Methods are inherited or overwritten from interface List to class ArrayList. Thus they are working the same.

Comment: Sorry its not about ArrayList is implementing List, but the elements in the list

Comment: @Jayr oh my.. Thank you for highlighting! That's a matter indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the index of an element in the list, use [List#indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-). There is no need to check if the list contains the element first because if it does not, the method returns `-1`.

Example:

```
List<String> players = new ArrayList<String>
players.addAll(Arrays.asList("Jim, "Bob, "Mary");

int indexOfBob = players.indexOf("Bob");
```

If you plan on iterating through the list and performing an operation on all the elements until you reach a specific one, you don't need to use two index integers. Example:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
    // Perform an operation on the current player.

    if(players.get(i).equals("Bob")) break;
}
```